# close windows phone 8 application inibm worklight?

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, back-button, close-application

WL.App.close() in ibm worklight is avaiable in wp 8?
I try to use this to quit my application when backbutton was pressed, but nothing've happened.
If this API is not avaiable to WP8, how can i make my app close when backbutton was pressed.

here's my code:

```
WL.App.overrideBackButton(backFunc);
    function backFunc() {
      if (isMapOn == true) {
         loadInfo();
       }
     else {
         WL.App.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the current version of Cordova does not support exiting the app on Windows phone.  See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/9v2kOwXj6sQ/O8SVpd-qjicJ

It may be supported in the future.